# Modify this class render, change the size of the progress bar to variable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering, jprogressbar

I have this code:

```
TableColumn column = jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
column.setCellRenderer(new ProgressRenderer());
```

class ProgressRenderer:

```
class ProgressRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private final JProgressBar b = new JProgressBar(0, 100);// I NEED RECEIVE DE VALUE,                //LIKE THIS new JProgressBar(0, MAX);
    private final JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    public ProgressRenderer() {
        super();
        setOpaque(true);
    b.setStringPainted(true);
        p.add(b);
        //p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Integer i = (Integer) value;

        String text = "Finalizou o Lote";
        if (i < 0) {
            text = "Pausa";
        } else if (i < 100) {
            b.setValue(i);
            return p;
        }
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, text, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUI() {
        super.updateUI();
        if (p != null) {
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need, When `ProgressRenderer` call function () difine a parameter which is the maximum of the progress bar, but I can not do, any idea?

Like this:

```
TableColumn column = jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    column.setCellRenderer(new ProgressRenderer(MAX));
```

Class ProgressRenderer()

```
class ProgressRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private final JProgressBar b = new JProgressBar(0, MAX);// I NEED RECEIVE DE VALUE,                //LIKE THIS new JProgressBar(0, MAX);
    private final JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    public ProgressRenderer() {
        super();
        setOpaque(true);
...
...
```

**----  Edit ----------**
thank you, but now have my big problem, because this:

```
TableColumn column = jTable2.getColumnModel () GetColumn (1).; 
    column.setCellRenderer (new ProgressRenderer (maxValue));//
```

// How do I know when to add the object to change the maxValue

I'm use this code for insert value in jtable

```
private LinhasOnline getLinha() {

    LinhasOnline linha = new LinhasOnline();
    linha.setNome("Linha "+j);
            linha.setcont(j*(10));
            linha.setmax(100);

            j++;
            return linha;
}

private void addLinha() {
    getModel().addLinha(getLinha());// 
}
```

//my getmodel

```
private LinhasOnlineTableModel getModel() {
    if (model == null) {
        model = (LinhasOnlineTableModel) getTblLinhasOnline().getModel();
    }
    return model;
}
```

//my getTblLinhasOnline()

```
 private JTable getTblLinhasOnline() {
    if (jTable2 == null) {
        jTable2 = new JTable();
        jTable2.setModel(new LinhasOnlineTableModel());
                    TableColumn column = jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
                    column.setCellRenderer(new ProgressRenderer(max)); // need put the value of object( setmax)
    }
    return jTable2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your class like next :

```
class ProgressRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private final JProgressBar b;// I NEED RECEIVE DE VALUE,                //LIKE THIS new JProgressBar(0, MAX);
    private final JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    public ProgressRenderer(int maxValue) {
        super();
        b  = new JProgressBar(0, maxValue);
        setOpaque(true);
        b.setStringPainted(true);
        p.add(b);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you, but now have other problem, see my edit comment, sorry because so must code, but for me is hard to explain. if you need a better explanation let me know :)